# Barplot in R - Recovering xlim and using par(new=T)

Tags: r

I need to do a barplot in R and then put a scatterplot on top of it with a new axis using `par(new=T)`.

If I set `xlim`, everything works nicely:

```
xx=c(0,12)
k=barplot(1:10,xlim=xx)
par(new=T)
plot(x=k,y=1:10/2,xlim=xx,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
axis(1,at=k,labels=1:10)
axis(4)
```

However, I need to do this without setting `xlim`. I thought `par('usr')` would solve my problems but I have been trying for a long time now without success.

Here is what I am using:

```
k=barplot(1:10)
xx=par('usr')[1:2]
par(new=T)
plot(x=k,y=1:10/2,xlim=xx,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
axis(1,at=k,labels=1:10)
axis(4)
```

In this case, the x-axis and new points are not properly centered. What am I doing wrong?

Just in case it is needed or useful in any way, here is the output of `R.Version()`:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "linux-gnu"
$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "3"
$minor
[1] "1.1"
$year
[1] "2014"
$month
[1] "07"
$day
[1] "10"
$`svn rev`
[1] "66115"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)"
$nickname
[1] "Sock it to Me"
```

**EDIT:**

This dirty hack (running barplot twice) solves the problem but it is far from being a proper solution:

```
k=barplot(1:10)
xx=par('usr')[1:2]
k=barplot(1:10,xlim=xx)
par(new=T)
plot(x=k,y=1:10/2,xlim=xx,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
axis(1,at=k,labels=1:10)
axis(4)
```

According to `?barplot`:

```
width
optional vector of bar widths. Re-cycled to length the
number of bars drawn. Specifying a single value will have no visible
effect unless xlim is specified.
```

It looks like the barplot is different when xlim is specified. Maybe this causes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You try to use `add=TRUE` option but you set the axes manually. This will complicate the task since each plot will create its own sacles and plot settings. Here is easier to use `points` to superpose your points once you create your barplot.

```
## set `ylim`  to not "cut" the last point.
k=barplot(1:10,ylim=c(0,11))
## points will use the plot scales already created
points(x=k,y=1:10/2,col='red',pch=20,cex=4)
axis(1,at=k,labels=1:10)
## to set new different axes in the right 
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x=k,y=1:10/2,type='n',xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
axis(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work because I need a new (and different) axis on the right.

Comment: @dd_rlwll what about my edit? Does this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. In your example, the new axis on the right does not serve any purpose because both the bars and the points are scaled according to the left axis. I need the red points to be able to use all the space available (hence the new axis) and I need to be able to code this in a way that does not require hardcoding of any parameters (including ylim) because the data set I have my hands on is not like this simple example I used to explain my question. Thanks for your help.